# ZBarReader Scans Only UPC_A format in iOS 6

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios6, barcode-scanner, zbar-sdk

I am developing BarCode reader app in **iOS 6**,

I am using `ZBar sdk`,  i developed app using this  [Tutorial..](http://zbar.sourceforge.net/iphone/sdkdoc/tutorial.html#create-the-app)
when i scans any barcode it scans only product of `UPC` format, but it doesn't scans the product of any other format like `EAN_13` or `Code_128` etc..

Here is my code snippet,

```
- (IBAction) scanButtonTapped
{

    ZBarReaderViewController *reader = [ZBarReaderViewController new];
    reader.readerDelegate = self;
    reader.supportedOrientationsMask = ZBarOrientationMaskAll;

    ZBarImageScanner *scanner = reader.scanner;

    [scanner setSymbology: ZBAR_I25
                   config: ZBAR_CFG_ENABLE
                       to: 0];

    [self presentViewController:reader animated:YES completion:nil];

}

- (void) imagePickerController: (UIImagePickerController*) reader
 didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: (NSDictionary*) info
{
    id<NSFastEnumeration> results =
    [info objectForKey: ZBarReaderControllerResults];
    ZBarSymbol *symbol = nil;
    for(symbol in results)
        break;

    NSLog(@"symbol.data=%@",symbol.data);

    [reader dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

How to scan product of all type ? any idea ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [Zbar FAQs](http://zbar.sourceforge.net/iphone/sdkdoc/faq.html)

> The ZBar decoder enables only EAN-13 by default

and

> The UPC-A symbology is the subset of EAN-13 that starts with a leading 0... You can choose to receive the 12-digit results instead by explicitly enabling UPC-A.

It sounds like EAN 13 is enabled. To enable Code 128, put the following snippet after you disable Interleaved 2 of 5 (I25)

```
[scanner setSymbology: ZBAR_CODE128
     config: ZBAR_CFG_ENABLE
     to: 1];
```

If you want strict control over what is enabled and disabled, disable all symbologies and selectively enable the ones you want

```
// Disable all symbologies
[scanner setSymbology: 0
     config: ZBAR_CFG_ENABLE
     to: 0];
// Enable EAN 13
[scanner setSymbology: ZBAR_EAN13
     config: ZBAR_CFG_ENABLE
     to: 1];
// Enable UPC-A
[scanner setSymbology: ZBAR_UPCA
     config: ZBAR_CFG_ENABLE
     to: 1];
// Enable Code 128
[scanner setSymbology: ZBAR_CODE128
     config: ZBAR_CFG_ENABLE
     to: 1]
```

Comment: I am unable to scan symbolody of type `code_128`, I want to enable all symbologies.. i wrote last paragraph u which you suggested.. am i write ?

Comment: Presumably, enabling all symbologies is the opposite of disabling them all. Try `[scanner setSymbology: 0 config: ZBAR_CFG_ENABLE to: 1];` The difference being `to: 1` instead of `to: 0`. Although the more symbologies you have enabled, the longer it will take to scan each barcode.